# UITextField disappears when tapped after animation

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

After making an animation on a UITextField, if I tap on my UITextField, it disappears. Why does this happen and how can I fix it? I'm not sure how to search for this online. Here's my animation code that I'm doing in viewDidAppear

```
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: [], animations: {

        self.userName.center.x += self.view.bounds.width
        self.userName.alpha = 1.0


        }, completion: nil)
```

Before this I set the UITextField to be off the screen. So what my animation is supposed to do is start from outside of the screen and animate it to be visibly in the center of the screen. Don't know if that makes a difference in this question though.

The animation works great, it's just that when I try to tap on the UITextField to enter a username, the entire UITextField just disappears and I'm left with just a keyboard. I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing. Can someone lead me in the right direction?

Comment: are you changing the frames for view or textfield in it's delegate methods?

Comment: A couple of things here... 1) Did you create this text field in a storyboard and if so did you place any auto layout constraints on it. If so, that's probably the issue right there. 2) If point one doesn't apply, try animating the field's frame directly instead of adjusting the it's center x.

Comment: Yes I am using auto layout in the storyboard. I don't understand why that would cause the issue?